# Parse function param to inner query is not possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am trying to execute this query but for some reason I seem to get this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 8:       FROM $1
```

Which I am not sure makes sense?
The function which should execute it is this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsrange_aggregate(_tbl regclass, selected_entity_id uuid, foreign_tsrange tsrange, OUT result Boolean)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE
 'SELECT $3 <@ (SELECT tsrange(min(COALESCE(lower(valid), ''-infinity'')), max(COALESCE(upper(valid), ''infinity'')))
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(nextstart > enddate OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY valid DESC NULLS LAST) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT valid
           , max(COALESCE(upper(valid), ''infinity'')) OVER (ORDER BY valid) AS enddate
           , lead(lower(valid)) OVER (ORDER BY valid) As nextstart
      FROM $1
      where entity_id = $2
      ) a
   ) b
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1);'
INTO result
USING _tbl, selected_entity_id, foreign_tsrange  ;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT tsrange_aggregate('parent_registration'::regclass, '0006f79d-5af7-4b29-a200-6aef3bb0105f', tsrange('2011-05-23 02:00:00', '2013-05-23 02:00:00' ));
```

is it not possible to function parameter to inner query? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that postgres cannot cope with a table called `$1`. You have to concatenate the table name in the variable with the string, e.g. using [`FORMAT`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-format/):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(text)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
DECLARE res boolean;
BEGIN
 EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT b FROM %I',$1) INTO res;
 RETURN res;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- `%I` treats the argument value as an SQL identifier.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7ca6a8dcc4172e40bd775fac50a026ba)